# Android viewpager not displayed in case other objects dynamically inflated below it

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, scrollviewer, layout-inflater

I am developing the specific type of a calendar showing events on some days and also showing events list of related month below the calendar. To do this, I benefit from [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid). Here is main xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context="com.vbs.android.caltest.MainActivity"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:overScrollMode="never"
  android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:weightSum="2"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/calendar1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical"/>



  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/eventsList"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Into calendar1 Caldroid is arranged. Here is the Caldroid xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="?styleCaldroidViewLayout"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendar_title_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calendar_left_arrow"
        style="?styleCaldroidLeftArrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_month_year_textview"
        style="?styleCaldroidMonthName"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calendar_right_arrow"
        style="?styleCaldroidRightArrow" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/weekday_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
   </GridView>

  <com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager
    android:id="@+id/months_infinite_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

So, screenshot of Caldroid app is :
[image]

The problem is that when I try to inflate events into eventsList(LinearLayout) the viewpager part of the Calendar not displayed. I use following method to inflate 3 textViews into eventsList:

```
   public void eventListFiller(){
    eventInflater = 
    (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    eventsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.eventsList);
    View eventContent;

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        eventContent = eventInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, null);
        TextView startDateTextView = 
      (TextView)   eventContent.findViewById(R.id.startDateTextView);
        TextView endDateTextView = 
     (TextView)   eventContent.findViewById(R.id.endDateTextView);
        TextView eventTitle =(TextView)eventContent.
        findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        startDateTextView.setText("startDate");
        endDateTextView.setText("endDate");
        eventTitle.setText(array[i]);
        eventsContainer.addView(eventContent);
    }

    Log.d("Runned", "EventsListFilled");
 }
```

Help me what problem is here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much Bence, I solved the problem through Mielet's (https://github.com/mielet) approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account the much more flexible library [DureyCalendarView](https://github.com/dureyingenieria/DureyCalendarView). It doesn't use a Fragment, you can place a custom view whenever you want, and you can easily define your XML layout.

Comment: Thank you very much Bence, I solved the problem through Mielet's (github.com/mielet) approach